# Generating spark dataframe from array but in shape of element not as an dataframe with array

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to generate dataframe from spark array but the schema of dataframe shouldn’t be dataframe(Array(int)) it should be Array(int). I want to put array element into dataframe but in shape of elements not as array.

```
val mean_array = Array.ofDim[int](2)
val date_array = Array.ofDim[String](2)
mean_array(0)=1
mean_array(1)=2
date_array(0)="dt1"
date_array(1)="dt2"
```

val ds = spark.createDataFrame( List(( date_array,mean_array)))
dsorg.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: array, _2: array]

Resulting array should be ds=[(1,dt1),(2,dt2)]

I want to take valeus inside the arrays and put it into new dataframe .

Comment: you should have mention properly - how your output would look.

Comment: I added to output and more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below

```
scala> val ds = spark.createDataFrame(mean_array zip date_array)
ds: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: int, _2: string]

scala> ds.show
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|  1|dt1|
|  2|dt2|
+---+---+
```

Please do let me know if it helps you.